# Multiprocess array processing C

Tags: arrays, c, multiprocessing

Im making an encryption program, where the goal is to get as many performance, and use least resources possible, so:
**Is there a way to multiprocess array processing function**
Exactly:

```
int encrypt(byte data[], size_t size, byte key[], int keyi, byte mode) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        data[i] += key[keyi]*mode;
        keyi=(keyi+1)*(key[keyi]=='\0');
    };
    return keyi;
}
```

It will be good if multiprocess code will be cross platform.
*I'm using latest gcc*
Here's the full code if necessary (don't be mad at me. Im just starting learning C)

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
typedef unsigned char byte;
byte isdir(byte *path) {
    struct stat statbuff;
    if (stat(path, &statbuff)!=0) {
        return 0;
    };
    return S_ISDIR(statbuff.st_mode);
};
void printa(byte a[]) {
    printf("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++) {
        printf("%d", a[i]);
        if (i != strlen(a) - 1) {
            printf(", ");
        };
    };
    printf("]\n");
};
int encrypt(byte data[], size_t size, byte key[], int keyi, byte mode) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        data[i] += key[keyi]*mode;
        keyi=(keyi+1)*(key[keyi]=='\0');
    };
    return keyi;
}
int encrypt_file(char *filename, char *filename2, byte key[], size_t buffer_size, byte mode) {
    byte *buff = calloc(sizeof(*buff), buffer_size);
    if (buff == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate memory. Consider lowering buffer_size\n");
        return 1;
    };
    FILE *f1 = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (f1 == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        free(buff);
        return 1;
    };
    FILE *f2 = fopen(filename2, "wb");
    if (f2 == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s: %s\n", filename2, strerror(errno));
        fclose(f1);
        free(buff);
        return 1;
    };
    size_t nread;
    int keyi = 0;
    while ((nread = fread(buff, sizeof(*buff), buffer_size, f1)) != 0) {
        keyi = encrypt(buff, nread, key, keyi, mode);
        if (fwrite(buff, sizeof(*buff), nread, f2) != nread) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to file %s: %s\n", filename2, strerror(errno));
            break;
        };
    };
    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
    free(buff);
    return 0;
};
int crypt_dir(char path[], byte key[], byte mode, int chunk_size) {
    byte in_path[256];
    byte out_path[256+4];
    byte lsym;
    byte code;
    byte renamed;
    byte scode=0;
    int file=0;
    int strl;
    struct dirent *dir;
    DIR *d;
    d=opendir(path);
    if (d) {
        while ((dir = readdir(d))!=NULL) {
            if (dir->d_type==DT_REG) {
                printf("%d'ng file\n", file);
                in_path[0]=out_path[0]='\0';
                strcat(in_path, path);
                strl=strlen(path)-1;
                lsym=path[strl];
                if (lsym!=47) {
                    strcat(in_path, "/");
                };
                strcat(in_path,dir->d_name);
                strcat(out_path, in_path);
                strcat(out_path, ".enc");
                file++;
                code=encrypt_file(in_path, out_path, key, chunk_size, mode);
                scode+=code;
                if (code==0) {
                    renamed=rename(out_path, in_path);
                    if (renamed!=0) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error renaming file. Does it exits? (%d)\n", renamed);
                    };
                };

            };
        };
    };
    return scode;
};
byte is_same(char s1[], char s2[]) {
    int len=0;
    if (strlen(s1)<strlen(s2)) {
        len=strlen(s1);
    } else {
        len=strlen(s2);
    };
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        if (s1[i]!=s2[i]) {
            return 0;
        };
    };
    return 1;
};
char find_interest(int argc, char *argv[], char interest[]) {
    for (int i=0; i<argc; i++) {
        if (is_same(argv[i], interest)) {
            return i;
        };
    };
    return -1;
};
char get_mode(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int loc;
    loc=find_interest(argc, argv, "-m")+1;
    if (loc!=0 && loc<argc) {
         if (is_same(argv[loc], "e")) {
            return 1;
         } else if (is_same(argv[loc], "d")) {
            return -1;
         } else {
            return 0;
         };
    } else {
        return 0;
    };
};
int get_chunk_size(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    byte loc;
    int val;
    char *end;
    loc=find_interest(argc, argv, "-cs")+1;
    if (loc!=0 && loc<argc) {
        val=strtol(argv[loc], &end, 10);
        if (strlen(end)==0) {
            return val;
        } else {
            printf("Invalid chunk size! Using default.\n");
            return 1024*10;
        };
    } else {
        return 1024*10;
    };
};
char get_key(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    byte loc;
    long val;
    loc=find_interest(argc, argv, "-k")+1;
    if (loc!=0 && loc<argc) {
        return loc;
    } else {
        return -1;
    };
};
char get_input(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    byte loc;
    long val;
    loc=find_interest(argc, argv, "-i")+1;
    if (loc!=0 && loc<argc) {
        return loc;
    } else {
        return -1;
    };
};
char get_output(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    byte loc;
    long val;
    loc=find_interest(argc, argv, "-o")+1;
    if (loc!=0 && loc<argc) {
        return loc;
    } else {
        return -1;
    };
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char mode=get_mode(argc, argv);
    int chunk_size=get_chunk_size(argc, argv);
    char key=get_key(argc, argv);
    char file1=get_input(argc, argv);
    char file2=get_output(argc, argv);
    if (mode==0) {
        printf("INVALID MODE!\nUse '-m e' to encrypt or '-m d' to decrypt\n");
        return 1;
    };
    if (key==-1) {
        printf("No key was specified! Use '-k KEY' to specify the key.\n");
        return 1;
    };
    if (file1==-1) {
        printf("No input was specified!\n Use '-i' to set path.\n");
        return 1;
    };
    byte filed=isdir(argv[file1]);
    if (!filed) {
        if (file2==-1) {
            printf("No output was specified!\n Use  '-o' to set path.\n");
            return 1;
        };
        printf("mode: %d\nchunk_size: %dB\nkey: %s\ninput: %s\noutput: %s\n", mode, chunk_size, argv[key], argv[file1], argv[file2]);
        return encrypt_file(argv[file1], argv[file2], (byte *)argv[key], chunk_size, mode);
    } else {
        if (file2!=-1) {
            printf("Output was specied despite input is a directory.\n-o HAS BEEN IGNORED!\n");
        };
        printf("mode: %d\nchunks_size: %dB\nkey: %s\ninput: %s\n", mode, chunk_size, argv[key], argv[file1]);
        return crypt_dir(argv[file1], (byte *)argv[key], mode, chunk_size);
    };
};
```

Comment: a few side comments, main must return int, dont use char when you want a number, it works but is confusing, just use 'int'. your  get_interest code is inspecting argv[0], thats the program name,start at 1. use strcmp to compare strings instead of 'is_same'

Comment: you would have to use threads or fork. Neither of these is portable to windows. If you coded in c++ you can use std::thread. Is there a reason to not use c++?

Comment: Using multiple processes means that you'll need to recombine their work somehow because each process has its own address space and its own copy of the arrays.  You might be able to place the array in shared memory, but it's getting complicated.  Using multiple threads is easier — at least they're all using the same array.  However, you must ensure that there is no risk that two different threads write to the same address at the same time, or that one thread reads from and another writes to the same address at the same time.  That may be trivial, or it may require synchronization primitives.

Comment: @pm100 fixed, sorry. No there is no reason to dont use C++

Comment: @Fun_Dan3 - so use std::thread then, this is portable and relatively eay to use